# Eclipse: Launch Failed. Binary not found

Tags: eclipse, windows

I have recently installed Eclipse C++ IDE onto windows and cannot resolve this issue. I have read all of what stackoverflow has suggested (including building the project.)

I used the Hello world template and am getting multiple errors.

> Program "g++" not found in PATH Program "gcc" not found in PATH Symbol
>   'cout' cannot be resolved Symbol 'endl' cannot be resolved Symbol
>   'std' cannot be resolved

I originally fixed the resolved errors but when I tried to compile/run the problem the binary error came up.

Answer (score 0):

Well, C compiler is not part of eclipse I think. You have to install gcc separately, then include it in the PATH variable.

Try this https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html

Comment: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\mingw\bin
-PATH Variable

C:\Users\Alex>gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.1

Comment: Maybe Eclipse uses it's own PATH. did you check Window/Preferences/C/C++? or search for PATH in prefs.

Comment: Or try creating Run/External Tools-Job which calls gcc just to check if it's found. Or one which runs "echo %PATH%"